# My flags are being declined. How do I get rid of these low-quality answers?

Tags: support

It's crystal clear these answers do not belong to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110666/is-rtp-nl-operational-yet). They are completely misleading and yet my flags are declined.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for raising this issue. It would seem that your flags are being denied because you should not use flags to mark wrong answers, and/or answers you disagree with. Indeed, the standard procedure for dealing with wrong answers is to downvote them, [not flag them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag). Quoting from the Meta.SE FAQs:

> ### When should I not use this flag?
>
> Do not use this flag when:
>
> - The user posts a partial answer to the issues presented in the question
> - The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it

In addition it helps to leave a comment explaining the downvote, so that the author can attempt to make the answer right.

Having said this, please refrain from using foul language on SE, as it is not tolerated.